# What kind of Json structure is this? 4-dimensional array?

Tags: json, servicestack

```
{"filters": 
[
    [
      "Color",
      [
        [
          "Blue",
          629,
          "t12-15=blue"
        ],
        [
          "Green",
          279,
          "t12-15=green"
        ]
      ]
    ],
    [
      "Style",
      [
        [
          "Contemporary / Modern",
          331,
          "t6-11=contemporary+modern"
        ],
        [
          "Transitional",
          260,
          "t6-11=transitional"
        ],
      ]
    ]
]}
```

This looks like a 4 dimensional array to me, but when I tried to use ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer to deserialize it, I do not get the expected result.

Looks like the values "Color" and "Style" are not in an array per se. What kind of Json structure is this?

Comment: What result did you expect?

Comment: I would like to be able to loop through the results in c#, but right now, accessing the "Color" value or "Style" value is a problem, because I am not sure what data structure to deserialize to in my c# code.

Answer (score 1):

To me it just looks like an object containing an array of arrays that goes 4 levels deep, so its an object with one field that is a [4D array](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multidimensional_array). if you want to get the 4D array you'll need to get the `filters` field from the json object returned

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed an array of arrays of arrays of arrays wrapped in an object. It's quite horrible, but I don't see why JsonSerializer would choke on it.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of structure? Irregular,  really. An object containing a field which contains an array which contains arrays in which the first item is a string, and the second item is an array containing two items which are arrays of string, number and string items .... phew!

Nothing wrong with this at all!

Comment: The interesting part is http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ can render it fine. I am just not sure how it's done, especially in c# / ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

It looks approximately like that Jackson might produce when you ask it to use arrays instead of objects to represent maps.

Answer (score 0):

Style and Color are just the first index of the arrays that they're in.  This is almost certainly NOT what was intended. If anything Style should probably be the label (object) for the next Array rather than its sibling, no?  The obvious follow-up question is who/what is producing this JSON, and who/what is consuming it... as bmarguiles asks... what *is your expectation here, given that the JSON is syntactically valid, if it's not doing what you expect... what do you expect?

**Edit based on your comment:**

well... since you seem to be able to rely on the fact that these are all nested arrays and that the label that you're looking for is going to be the 0th index of whatever array, you can just recurse into the array looking for that label and then treating the array that is at the 1st index with the assumption that it will contain the data you expect. It's ugly, but it looks like it will work (so long as the service that generates this doesn't change). C# has a JSON deserializer [james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) . You should just use that.

Comment: The JSON is produced by a search service provider, and we are the consumer. 

I would like to be able to loop through the results in c#, but right now, accessing the "Color" value or "Style" value is a problem, because I am not sure what data structure to deserialize to in my c# code.